# AngularJS mock ngChange for select in Unit test

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

I want to UT a onchange event for a select box.

HTML -

```
<select id="basetype" ng-model="role.baseType"
        ng-options="basePolicy"
        ng-change="populateSettingsForBaseType()">
</select>
```

Controller event handler -

```
private addBaseTypeChangeHandler(): void {
    this.$scope.populateSettingsForBaseType = () => {
      //someCode
    };
}
```

I want to verify that event handler is called onchange event -

```
it('should add the certificate validator', function() {
      spyOn($scope, 'populateSettingsForBaseType').and.callThrough();
      const html = '<select id="basetype" ng-change="populateSettingsForBaseType()" ng-model="model"></select>';

      const element = $compile(html)($scope);

      const elem = element.find('select').trigger('change');

      const ngModel = element.controller('ngModel');
      ngModel.$viewValue = 'full';

      $scope.$digest();
      expect($scope.populateSettingsForBaseType).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
```

This isn't working. What is the right way to trigger event and ensure that handler is being invoked from a UT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
it('should add the certificate validator', function() {
      spyOn($scope, 'populateSettingsForBaseType').and.callThrough();
      const html = '<select id="basetype" ng-change="populateSettingsForBaseType()" ng-model="model"></select>';

      const element = $compile(html)($scope);

      ̶c̶o̶n̶s̶t̶ ̶e̶l̶e̶m̶ ̶=̶ ̶e̶l̶e̶m̶e̶n̶t̶.̶f̶i̶n̶d̶(̶'̶s̶e̶l̶e̶c̶t̶'̶)̶.̶t̶r̶i̶g̶g̶e̶r̶(̶'̶c̶h̶a̶n̶g̶e̶'̶)̶;̶

      const ngModel = element.controller('ngModel');
      ̶n̶g̶M̶o̶d̶e̶l̶.̶$̶v̶i̶e̶w̶V̶a̶l̶u̶e̶ ̶=̶ ̶'̶f̶u̶l̶l̶'̶;̶
      ngModel.$setViewValue('full');

      $scope.$digest();
      expect($scope.populateSettingsForBaseType).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
```

Comment: aah... not the variable but method. Silly mistake!